# Is there a way to have the tooltips always shown on a pie/doughnut in Chart.js v3?

Tags: chart.js, chart.js3

I'm trying to have the tooltips always shown on a doughnut in Chart.js v3. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Not by default, if you want to see all the values all the time you are better of using the datalabels plugin: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is not exactly what I'm looking for, but it is indeed a great alternative. Thanks!